# Is the sum of the medians of two sequential events a meaningful statistic?

Tags: time-series, descriptive-statistics, median, finite-population

Say I have two types of events $A$ and $B$ which happen to an individual entity, where $A$ is necessary for $B$ to occur, and $B$ starts right away after $A$. Also say we can split up the entities into sub-populations, and I have time data of when $A$ starts, when $B$ starts, (the same time that $A$ ends,) and when $B$ ends for many different entities, and that data is labeled with which sub-population each entity comes from.

With that data I can calculate the medians of the $A$ durations and of the $B$ durations, for each sub-population. is the sum of those two medians, a meaningful statistic? Say that we want to make decisions about the sub-populations based on how long we expect the total duration from $A$ beginning to $B$ ending to be for future entities from each sub-population. Does it make sense to use the sum of the medians for this purpose? If not, is there a more meaningful statistic that can be calculated from that data?

Comment: Medians are not really designed to be added together or averaged.  If that sort of thing matters, consider using means instead

Comment: Suppose the A values were $(2,3,10)$ with median $3$ and the B values were $(10,2,3)$ with median $3$.  The the sum of the medians would be $3+3=6$ but the median of the sums of $(12,5,13)$ would be $12$.  Meanwhile the sum of the means would be $5+5=10$ and the mean of the sums would also be $10$

Comment: A more meaningful statistic is the median of the total duration.

Comment: @Henry What if the data is known to have many outliers, which originally prompted the use of the median? In particular, in a report that includes the $A$ median and $B$ median, switching to the mean afterwards seems odd.

Comment: @MattF. As Henry demonstrated, the median of the summed durations, is not always the sum of the medians. When the median of the summed duration is presented alongside the two other medians, it looks strange, as if there is a problem with the calculations.